# JSPX drop down list

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-adf, jspx

I am writing a oracle ADF fusion web app using jdeveloper 11.1.2.0.0. In a jspx page I have a drop down list which is populated by a menu model. I want it to be shown expanded when the page loads in the browser.
Please give me an idea.

Thanks
Sameera

Answer (score 1):

Consider using another type of component instead of a drop down.
For example how about just using an iterator to show the list of options?

Comment: I agree, use an iterator or a listbox. This pre-expanded dropdown violates the principle of least-astonishment.

Answer (score 0):

There is no programmatic(meaning javascript) way of triggering the disclosure of a native dropdown element. As advised by others, consider using a different UI strategy. Maybe an af:table that is selectable?

Answer (score 0):

it is true that there is no direct or programmatic way to emulate the triggering of click event on a dropdown to open it, but you can do this by the following code. What you need are:

1. [jquery-1.7.1.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js)
2. [ExpandSelect.js](http://expandselect.googlecode.com/files/ExpandSelect_1.00.js)

The bean who supplies the List of SelectItem is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

public class BackBean {
    private List<SelectItem> options;

    public BackBean() {
        options = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(0);
        options.add(new SelectItem("Option 1", "Option 1"));
        options.add(new SelectItem("Option 2", "Option 2"));
        options.add(new SelectItem("Option 3", "Option 3"));
        options.add(new SelectItem("Option 4", "Option 4"));
        options.add(new SelectItem("Option 5", "Option 5"));
    }

    public void setOptions(List<SelectItem> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }
}
```

And the jspx page is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" version="2.1" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
          xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <f:view>
        <af:document title="Home" id="d1">
            <af:form id="f1">
                <af:resource type="javascript" source="/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"/>
                <af:resource type="javascript" source="/js/ExpandSelect.js"/>
                <af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1">
                    <f:facet name="center">
                        <af:selectOneChoice label="Menu" id="soc1" clientComponent="true" styleClass="menu">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{backingBeanScope.backBean.options}" id="si1"/>
                        </af:selectOneChoice>
                    </f:facet>
                </af:panelStretchLayout>
            </af:form>            
            <af:resource type="javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){                    
                    ExpandSelect(document.getElementById($($('.menu > tbody > tr > td').next().find('select')).attr('id')));
                });
            </af:resource>            
        </af:document>
    </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

Here is the screenshot I have:
[image]

Hope this will help. Let me know your feedback.